# how to calculate this string with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

```
private static void ReceivedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        string text = Regex.Replace(e.Data, "^\\s+$[\\r\\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        if (text.Contains("My Own String:"))
        {
            combinedOutput = Regex.Split(text, ":")[1].ToString().Trim();
            combinedAuth = true;
        }
        if (!(text == "") && !(text == Environment.NewLine) && !(text == " ") && text != null && !(text == "\r\n") && !(text == "\n"))
        {
            combinedError = text;
        }
    }
}
```

This code I have from the program that does read some strings
for example, string text contains "1bc4bb7de4c58a7eba6b95b565b21a4b26b5528c2be242b96fe014bf7ff403ca"
and than it replaces/calculates the string with Regular Expressions: ^\s+$[\r\n]* like the code I put above. I can't seem to understand it. This looks pretty simple but I can't make it. So if anyone who can understand this code and help me calculate the response?
I suppose the response will also be 32 bytes.
Cheers!

Comment: It appears to be searching for one or more whitespace characters followed by carriage return and linefeed and then removing them by replacing them with an empty string..

Comment: I would just use string Trim() method : e.Data.Trim().

Comment: Regexes don't calculate, they match (or not)  a string.

Comment: `Regex.Replace(e.Data, "^\\s+$[\\r\\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline)` removes blank lines, it does not calculate anything. What output do you need for `1bc4bb7de4c58a7eba6b95b565b21a4b26b5528c2be242b96fe014bf7ff403ca` string?

Comment: Looks a bit like it's also expecting the string to come in with "My Own String: " and then the rest of the string after that.

Comment: @Nick Read, My Own Strings is : 1bc4bb7de4c58a7eba6b95b565b21a4b26b5528c2be242b96fe014bf7ff403ca

Answer (score 0):

#### This code is performing text processing.

---

```cs
string text = Regex.Replace(e.Data, "^\\s+$[\\r\\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

This first segment of code is used to take any multiline input it receives and strip out all empty lines, essentially getting a block of text with no breaks between each line. This leaves leading and trailing whitespace on each line.

`^\s+$[\r\n]*` is a regex used to strip empty lines from an input string.

- `^\s+$` Match a line that contains nothing but whitespace
- `[\r\n]*` Match any number of newlines or return characters after this empty line.

The second piece of the regex is necessary because otherwise, a pair of newlines between two lines of input would be left in place. Note that a similar effect could be achieved with `^\s+$\s*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DwHBvS/3/)

---

```cs
        if (text.Contains("My Own String:"))
        {
            combinedOutput = Regex.Split(text, ":")[1].ToString().Trim();
            combinedAuth = true;
        }
```

Once the text has been reduced to a single line, those lines are checked to see if they begin with the phrase `My Own String:` - if they do, the phrase is removed via `Regex.Split()` by breaking on the colon. The resulting string is then trimmed to remove leading and trailing whitespace. If the text did NOT begin with `My Own String:`, any leading or trailing whitespace is left intact.

---

```cs
        if (!(text == "") && !(text == Environment.NewLine) && !(text == " ") && text != null && !(text == "\r\n") && !(text == "\n"))
        {
            combinedError = text;
        }
```

The text is now examined. If...

- `!(text == "")` The string isn't empty, and...
- `!(text == Environment.NewLine)` The string does not consist of solely a newline (on Unix) or a newline and carriage return (on Windows), and...
- `!(text == " ")` The string does not consist of solely a space, and...
- `text != null` The string is not `null`, and...
- `!(text == "\r\n")` The string does not consist of a carriage return and a newline, and...
- `!(text == "\n")` The text does not consist solely of a newline...

...then `combinedError` is set equal to the processed and checked string. I believe this segment of code could be significantly refactored; checking for `null` is usually the first conditional statement to avoid NullPointerExceptions, and `Environment.NewLine` covers both `\r\n` and `\n`.